# stored procedure to transfer data from a table in one database to a table in another database in oracle

Tags: oracle9i

there are 2 databases A AND B. i want to transfer data from a table in A TO a table in B. i want to use cursor for this. the duplicate datas when transferring should go to a table called duplicat table. I want a stored procedure to do the above. first i need to connect database A with database B using db link. i want the complete stored procedure. can anyone help plzzzzzzzzzz...........

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you look for guidance rather then complete answer here, if you want to learn....

Google for how to create db link in oracle and how to use that in queries. Once this is done you just use the remote table as a normal table.

Following links are useful

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_admin002.htm

http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm